# Существует ли в литературном языке такое слово - "найдешевейший"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если нет, то чем его заменить?

Answer (score 1):

Только без первого "Й": на**и**дешёвейший - находится гуглом в нескольких десятках *книг* (если не обращать внимания на рекламщиков, у которых это слово явно востребовано). Пример:

> *Не то чтобы путь этот, требующий выработки и сравнительно длинный и*
>   *медленный, был **наидешевейший** по сравнению с прямым железнодорожным...*
>   (Проблемы экономического развития России. Дмитрий Иванович Менделеев)

Answer (score 0):

В литературном - нет: слишком много превосходных степеней и абсолютно чужое языку "й" в префиксе "наи".

Как просторечие - да, произносящий будет понят.

Замена - самый дешёвый.

Русское словесное ударение разрешает форму *дешевейший:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В "наилучшем" столько же степеней (две).

Comment: В каком таком ещё "налучшем"?! О_о "Найдешевейший" оказалось украинцем.

Comment: Буква "и" выпала от покраснения за "Й" :)

Comment: Саш, а это тема!.. Задавай вопрос!